# How to display toast message using iziToast

Tags: jquery, laravel, message, toast

I'm going to display message in my laravel project using iziToast.
In my "custom.js" file, I have ajax function.

```
success: function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                        itoastr('success', res.success);
                    }
```

when success, I need to display message from controller or some other message.
But when success, toast not working and it shows such console error.

```
iziToast.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at iziToast.min.js:6
    at Object.e.show (iziToast.min.js:6)
    at Object.e.<computed> [as success] (iziToast.min.js:6)
    at itoastr (custom.js:282)
    at Object.success (custom.js:467)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

This "custom.js" file is in register.blade.php file and it extends from layout/front.blade.php .
And in front.blade.php file I included izitoast like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('assets/izitoastr/iziToast.min.js') !!}"></script>
```

It will be thankful to anyone who give me quick and detailed answer.

Comment: The problem isn't in the last snippet because the error comes from `iziToast.min.js:6` which means the script been loaded. I don't know iziToast but I wonder about how you call it because the docs shows `iziToast.show(` as the way to call it but you're doing it differentially.

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This

```
iziToast.success({message: response.message});
iziToast.error({title:'Error',message: response.message});

iziToast.info({
    title: 'Hello',
    message: 'Welcome!',
});
```

[ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/izitoast/v/1.0.2-b)